# Stay Logged In Cookies with Qt Webview

Tags: c++, qt, cookies, qwebview

**Background on the program (in case that helps):**

I'm trying to make a simple wrapper to go around "web applications" to give them some of the look/feel + isolation that a traditional application brings. I understand that using web technologies makes it way easier to develop for cross platform (especially when it comes to the UI) but I don't like how it has become a sort of catch all solution for lots of dev teams. I don't want to run software inside my web browser.

Browsers are heavy and support a wide range of functions that aren't relevant to what the application does and having a program function entirely in a browser tab can lead to a clunky user experience (I'm looking at you Bittorrent Sync for linux). Instead I would rather use a stripped down browser that is much lighter and runs in its own isolated space rather than in the browser ecosystem.

Additional functionally can be easily tacked on to provide a more fluid user experience (for example if the user doesn't start the program and tries to connect to it through a browser they are going to get HTTP error codes. In this separate wrapper the program could read the error code itself and show some preloaded html to give a more useful error specific to the program).

To accomplish this I am trying to use Qt to create a browser that is simply a web render-er, http communicator, cookie support, and some basic management features (shortcuts for running the program instead of relying on the command line)

**PROBLEM:**

Checking the "Stay Signed In" box does nothing. I'm pretty sure the way stay signed in works is the server generates an authentication for the browser to store as a cookie.

When I sign into my google account I can see several cookies that are created after logging in that appear to do just that. I can have access to my gmail, calendar, etc. and when I exit the non session cookies are stored to the disk.

When I start the program back up they are loaded from the disk and appear in each request, but I am not signed into an account and the sign in link is visible. If I don't log in again, the old cookies aren't stored to disk again when the program exists.

Here is some debug output of the cookies when I close the program when logged in (cookies saved to disk) then restart the program (loaded from disk) and close it without logging in again (cookies saved):

```
SAVING COOKIES

GAPS=1:8-XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
NID=XXXXX; HttpOnly; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2016 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SID=XXXXX; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
LSID=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
HSID=XXXXX; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SSID=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
APISID=XXXXX; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SAPISID=XXXXX; secure; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
ACCOUNT_CHOOSER=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:LD=en:TM=XXXXX:LM=XXXXX:V=1:S=XXXXX_rr5; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
OGPC=5-2:; expires=Sat, 01-Aug-2015 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
OTZ=XXXXX; secure; expires=Sat, 01-Aug-2015 17:34:15 GMT; domain=plus.google.com; path=/
build-WebView-Desktop-Debug/WebView exited with code 0


LOADING COOKIES

GAPS=1:8-XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
NID=XXXXX; HttpOnly; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2016 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SID=XXXXX; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
LSID=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
HSID=XXXXX; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SSID=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
APISID=XXXXX; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
SAPISID=XXXXX; secure; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
ACCOUNT_CHOOSER=XXXXX; secure; HttpOnly; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=accounts.google.com; path=/
PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:LD=en:TM=XXXXX:LM=XXXXX:V=1:S=XXXXX_rr5; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
OGPC=5-2:; expires=Sat, 01-Aug-2015 17:34:10 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
OTZ=XXXXX; secure; expires=Sat, 01-Aug-2015 17:34:15 GMT; domain=plus.google.com; path=/


SAVING COOKIES

PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=XXXXX:LM=XXXXX:V=1:S=XXXXX; expires=Sat, 01-Jul-2017 17:34:51 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
NID=XXXXX; HttpOnly; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2016 17:34:51 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
OGPC=5-2:; expires=Sat, 01-Aug-2015 17:35:03 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/
```

I replaced some keys and numbers with XXXXX to avoid posting anything important online.

Here's the source code producing this output:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //Manager to allow use of cookiejar
    QNetworkAccessManager* nam = new QNetworkAccessManager;

   //Used for debug, prints out all cookies after each request is finished
   connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(echo(QNetworkReply*)));

    //create and assign cookiejar to nam
    jar = new CookieJar();
    nam->setCookieJar(jar);

    //create webview and assign nam to it
    webview = new QWebView();
    webview->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(nam);

    //Display cookies loaded from disk
    const QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = jar->getCookies();
    std::cout << std::endl << "Cookies From Disk:" << std::endl << std::endl;
    for(QNetworkCookie cookie: cookies)
        std::cout << cookie.toRawForm().data() << std::endl;

    //Load the test url
    QUrl url("http://www.google.com");
    webview->load(url);

    //place webview on screen
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(webview);

}

//Used for debug, prints out all cookies after each request is finished
void MainWindow::echo(QNetworkReply *reply){
        const QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies2 = jar->getCookies();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Cookies After HTTP:" << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(QNetworkCookie cookie: cookies2)
        std::cout << cookie.toRawForm().data() << std::endl;


}
```

Relevant parts of my cookiejar implementation:

```
bool CookieJar::saveCookiesToDisk(){
    std::ofstream output("cookies.dat");

    this->purgeOldCookies();

    if(output){
        QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = this->allCookies();

        std::cout << "\nSAVING COOKIES" << std::endl << std::endl;

        for(QNetworkCookie cookie: cookies)
            if(!cookie.isSessionCookie()){
                std::cout << cookie.toRawForm().data() << std::endl;
                output << cookie.toRawForm().data() << this->COOKIE_DELIMITER;
            }

        output.close();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


bool CookieJar::loadCookiesFromDisk(){
    std::ifstream input("cookies.dat");

    if(input){
        QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies;

        std::string cookieData;

        std::cout << "\nLOADING COOKIES" << std::endl << std::endl;

        while(getline(input, cookieData, this->COOKIE_DELIMITER)){
            std::cout << cookieData << std::endl;
            cookies.append(QNetworkCookie(QByteArray(cookieData.c_str(), cookieData.length())));
        }

        this->setAllCookies(cookies);

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * This function comes from the official qt demo at
 *      http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-browser-cookiejar-cpp.html
 */
void CookieJar::purgeOldCookies(){

    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = allCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty())
        return;
    int oldCount = cookies.count();
    QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    for (int i = cookies.count() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!cookies.at(i).isSessionCookie() && cookies.at(i).expirationDate() < now)
            cookies.removeAt(i);
    }
    if (oldCount == cookies.count())
        return;
    setAllCookies(cookies);
    //This last line from the example was omitted as it is not relevant to the function of this project?
    //emit cookiesChanged();
}
```

Any help figuring out why my stored cookies seem to be ignored by the server would be greatly appreciated. As far as I can tell I am properly storing and sending all cookies so I wouldn't be surprised if I've oversimplified how these authentication cookies work.

Thank you to anyone taking time out of their day to help me out here.

Comment: if I add the line `webview->page()->networkAccessManager()->cookieJar()->setCookiesFromUrl(jar->getCookies(), url);` before calling `webview->load()` it will remember my account but require that I reenter my password on the next launch. If I don't reenter my password it will show sign in instead of the account picture on subsequent logins

Comment: Is it possible or desirable to change to token based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I have an working example of a 'stay logged' application, here are the load&save functions:

```
bool loadLoginCookie()
{
    QDir cookiesDir("dir where cookie is stored");
    if(! cookiesDir.exists())
    {
        return false;
    }

    QFile cookieFile(cookiesDir.path() + "/cookie.dat");
    if(! cookieFile.exists())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(! cookieFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error reading the cookie file:" << cookieFile.fileName();
    }

    QByteArray cookieRaw = cookieFile.readAll();
    cookieFile.close();

    QList<QNetworkCookie> newCookies = QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(cookieRaw);
    if (newCookies.count() == 0 && cookieRaw.length() != 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "CookieJar: Unable to parse saved cookie:" << cookieRaw;
    }

    QNetworkManager& myAppNetworkManager =Application::getInstance().getNetworkManager();
    myAppNetworkManager.fillCookiesJar(newCookies, QUrl("theurl:443"));

    foreach (QNetworkCookie cookie, newCookies)
    {
        if(cookie.name() == "connect.sid") //loging cookie
        {
            Application::getInstance().setLoginCookie(cookie); //here i save the login cookie in a class QNetworkCookie*
            qDebug() << "cookie loaded";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Error loading the login cookie.";
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool Application::saveLoginCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie)
{
    QDir cookiesDir("dir where cookie must be stored");
    if(! cookiesDir.exists())
    {
        if(! cookiesDir.mkpath("."))
        {
            qDebug() << "Error creating the cookies directory";
            return false;
        }
    }

    QFile cookieFile(cookiesDir.path() + "/cookie.dat");
    if(! cookieFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error saving the cookie file:" << cookieFile.fileName();
        return false;
    }

    cookieFile.write(cookie.toRawForm());
    cookieFile.close();

    qDebug() << "Login cookie created successfully.";
    return true;
});
```

This save function is called after the login operation:

```
QVariant cookieVar = reply.header(QNetworkRequest::SetCookieHeader);//reply is the QNetworkReply returned by the login operation
if(cookieVar.isValid())
{
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = cookieVar.value<QList<QNetworkCookie> >();
    foreach (QNetworkCookie cookie, cookies)
        {
            if(cookie.name() == "connect.sid") //loging cookie
            {                       
               if(! saveLoginCookie(cookie))
                {
                    qDebug() << "Error saving login cookie";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Login cookie not valid";
    }
}
```

I know that its not a reimplementation of the cookieJar but it maybe gives you inspiration. We can discuss it further if you can't make it work.